# Does a sapper affect a large robot beyond disabling his allies?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy, tf2-mann-vs-machine

The spy's sapper can be a fairly decent fair to disable a large group of robots, though usually only have to leveling it up.   It's also great for holding targets still for back-stabs.

The only problem is that when a spy saps a large robot, that robot will not stop moving or even attacking.   The large robot does seem to visually glitch a little, you can see the sparking sapper, for instance, and the robot tends to bend over a little...(lol)

What effects does a sapper have on a large robot?

Does the sapper have any effects other than temporarily disabling a small robot and his allies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Community_Mann_vs._Machine_strategy#.C2.A0Spy):

> Upgraded Sappers can disable robots in a radius and slow down giant robots to make them easier to destroy.

It seems that sappers don't actually stop giant robots, just slow them down.

Comment: I saw this today in a tip section for the game as well.